# firefox extension : Main has no authority to run load

Tags: firefox-addon

I am trying to run obfuscated code.
ERR :

console.error: project:

```
Message: Error: Module: project/main has no authority to load: sdk/tabs
```

Stack:

```
@project/main:108:undefined
```

Comment: Please include your source code in the question.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Code can be unobfuscated. Is this your own extension, or something you got elsewhere?  If your own, does the error occur when it is not obfuscated?

Answer (score 1):

When your add-on imports a module through `require`, this does not happen unconditionally. The name of the module is checked against a list of the modules that your source code actually uses. This list is determined during the packaging of the add-on.

So, during development your (non-obfuscated) code is packaged fine and runs ok.

But by the time you decide that the add-on is ready for deployment, you replace the code with the obfuscated version and execute `cfx xpi`.

Now the script responsible for building the aforementioned list cannot find any `require("module")` command in the source code, the list remains empty and subsequently every `require` fails during runtime.

You can manually edit that list. Inside the `xpi` there is a `harness-options.json` file, locate the `manifest` object and inside this the `requirements` list of key/value pairs. That's it. You can copy the list from an `xpi` packaged with the non-obfuscated code.

Although you should also ask your self if the obfuscation is really worth the trouble (this and others that you haven't come across yet).